# Convert React Native project to traditional android studio project

Tags: android, react-native

I recently started to learn react and want to know if, It is possible to convert a react-native project to a normal android project that could be continued and coded completely in Android Studio?

I know I can open android directory with android studio and do some changes at the current state (while react-native still need) but I want to completely remove any dependency of react-native and node module from continuing developing the application.

If no, (that I expect the answer be this!) please describe a little about reason. (If I be correct, in react-native, layouts are same as original android widgets, but I'm not sure about possibility of converting ES6 to Java.)

Comment: Can you please share typical project structure you used in your react native project? How many view files are present in your react native project?

Comment: @SatishSojitra I can't understand exactly what you need! Think about a normal project initialized from `react-native init exampleproject`